# Using environment variables in icecast config

Tags: xml, server, configuration, environment-variables, icecast

I'm trying to setup the icecast.xml file to pull in necessary variables from the environment. For example I have set the variable `HOST=streamurl.com` and I want to pull that variable in the config: `<hostname>$HOST</hostname>`

However I don't see much in their documentation so I don't know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Icecast does not support this.**

In addition the hostname field takes a FQDN, not an URL. Doing otherwise will e.g. break YP listings.

What are you trying to achieve here? There might be a better/easier way.

Comment: I realize now that I messed up the example I am using an FQDN not a URL.

I am trying to have distinct urls depending on environments. Right now we have a `stream.url.com`  and I'm trying to setup `stream-staging.url.com`

Comment: There are many ways. One of them is just a quick `sed -i /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml s/HOSTNAMEPLACEHOLDER/$HOSTNAME/g` (modulo proper syntax etc.)